# Alternative to POST json (or can json object 'post'ed can be improved)

Tags: python, json, rest, curl

I am using POST to dump json input to my api for processing.

When I see the input decoded by my api. The response is

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('record[2]', '1902'), ('disabled[2]', 'False'), ('record[1]', '1901'), ('date', '2016-11-17'), ('debet[1]', '11'), ('kredit[2]', '22'), ('kredit[1]', '12'), ('debet[2]', '21'), ('description', 'Domännamn'), ('disabled[1]', 'False')].
```

It is very difficult to deal with ImmutableMultiDict. I am not able to extract the details out of it. Is there any value to beautify the same or any better way to deal with it?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: client side I am using postman to send json. not much in code.

Comment: How exactly does the JSON look then? What are you using to get the JSON into that object? There has to be some code that’s receiving it and handling it, it doesn’t just magically appear in Python

Comment: json is something like this:

{
    {
        "record": 1901,
        "debet": 11,
        "kredit": 12,
        "disabled": False
    },
    {
        "record": 1902,
        "debet": 21,
        "kredit": 22,
        "disabled": False
    }
}

What is shown in question is value extracted from "request.values"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImmutableMultiDict sounds like a Flask thing. That type has to_dict method to convert to regular python dictionary, so:

```
imd = ImmutableMultiDict([('record[2]', '1902'), ('disabled[2]', 'False'), ('record[1]', '1901'), ('date', '2016-11-17'), ('debet[1]', '11'), ('kredit[2]', '22'), ('kredit[1]', '12'), ('debet[2]', '21'), ('description', 'Domännamn'), ('disabled[1]', 'False')]
imd.to_dict()
```

You might try also:

```
imd.to_dict(flat=False)
```

if you need to return list instead of single value for keys

Answer (score 1):

Try this below wherever your api is deconding the response:

```
respose = ImmutableMultiDict([('record[2]', '1902'), ('disabled[2]', 'False'), ('record[1]', '1901'), ('date', '2016-11-17'), ('debet[1]', '11'), ('kredit[2]', '22'), ('kredit[1]', '12'), ('debet[2]', '21'), ('description', 'Domännamn'), ('disabled[1]', 'False')]

response_dict = response.to_dict()
print(response_dict)
```